# I wanted to import Excel sheet as it is(i.e with column name as that of excelsheet)?

Tags: excel, postgresql, postgis

Hi i am new to postgreSql. I wanted to import excel sheet as it is with column name/heading because excel sheet have nearly 80-100 columns and i cannot create table with such huge numbers of columns and then copy same data to table. So i want alternate way for same to import data to table along with column name.

Comment: What happens when you try to create the table?

Comment: What are the errors that pops up on your way so far?

Comment: i have many columns so i have to create table with nearly 80 to 90 columns while creating report. so i want to add excel sheet as it is. I know how to copy by creating table and then copy csv to created table but in my case it would time consuming!

Answer (score 1):

Create an ODBC connection to your PostgreSQL database. You need to have a PostgreSQL ODBC Database driver, which is simple to download and install. Save as a User DSN for future use.

To process your Excel data, import the Excel spreadsheet into MS Access. If the data looks good and "database like", then you are good, otherwise the spreadsheet might need to be adjusted to import correctly.

With the final MS Access table, right-click the table and Export to ODBC Database, choosing the DSN you created above, which you find in the "Machine Data Source" tab.